# How to display input data with sentence with the help of JS/html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

Ok so I want to create something like this.
html page will shows sentence with input field.

ex. My name is '--------@input field@-----------'
After hitting ok It will show output like

welcome '@data from input field@'.

Comment: Please post your current code and what is wrong with it. Nobody will create your homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var person = prompt("What is your name");

if (person !== "") {
      alert("Hello : " + person);
}
```

There you go. That's some very basic javascript, are you sure you googled before asking the question?